# Visual studio code shortcut for commenting with a german keyboard layout

Tags: layout, keyboard, visual-studio-code, shortcut

What is the alternative shortcut for commenting lines on the German keyboard layout in visual studio code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The shortcut is:

```
STRG + #
```

I have to type few extra words because stackoverflow doesn't want to have short answers.

Comment: Why is it superlong?

Comment: for me it was Strg + Shift + # for block comment, how crazy this website is  that I made a plus point to you and in less than a second to find the other one was removed.

Comment: this answer should be the accepted one. short and precisely answers the question.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if it somehow related to my installation, but my vscode uses by default following shortcuts:

```
Ctrl-K + Ctrl-C - comment
Ctrl-K + Ctrl-U - uncomment
```

They works with German layout and I can change it to whatever I want using

```
File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Search for "line comment"
```

Comment: I think you set VSCode to use Visual Studio key mapping.

Comment: Isn't that default? VSCode to use Visual Studio key mapping?

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answer: if you don't know a shortcut on your keyboard, you can look it up under File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts.
Search for the command you want to look up and hover over the blue "i" icon. This will show you the key on your keaboard.

So for your example, you will search for "comment" or something like that and find the mapped key as "ctrl+/" with an blue i icon beneath it. Hover over the icon and it will say: "For your current keyboard layout press Ctrl+#".

More information and how you can fix all the shortcuts for your layout can be found here: [VSCode Github Wiki: Keybinding-Issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues#troubleshoot-windows-keybindings)

Edit: Link to microsofts vscode github wiki changed

Comment: This is an old comment but I came to this problem today and have an additional solution... When you open up the command palette with a german keyboard it will show the required key. I had the problem with ```Ctrl+Shift+\ Jump to matching bracket```. It is ```Ctrl+Shift+^``` in german.

Answer (score 2):

For Mac-Users, it is:

> Shift + CMD + 7

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).